# Conditional elementwise multiplication of two pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I am struggling doing a basic conditional elementwise multiplication between two dataframes. 
Let's assume I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-0.1,0.3,-0.4, 0.8,-0.5,-0.1,0.3,-0.4, 0.8,-1.2],'B': [-0.2,0.5,0.3,-0.5,0.1,-0.2,0.5,0.3,-0.5,0.9]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'C': [-0.003,0.03848,-0.04404, 0.018,-0.1515,-0.02181,0.233,-0.0044, 0.01458,-0.015],'D': [-0.0152,0.0155,0.03,-0.0155,0.0151,-0.012,0.035,0.0013,-0.0005,0.009]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

The idea is to multiply `df1 and df2.shift(-1)` (elementwise, not matrix multiplication) depending on the values of df1. If `(df1>=0.50 or df1<=-0.50)` then I multiply df1 and df2.shift(-1). Otherwise, I just put 0.

The desired result in this example should be the following (with columns names being the column names of df1 as well as df1 index):

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0, -0.1212,0.010905,0,0,0, -0.012,'NaN'],'B': [0,0.015,0,-0.00755,0,0,0.00065,0,-0.0045,'NaN']},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df3=np.where((df1>=0.50 or df1 <=-0.50),df1*df2.shift(-1),0)
```

And I get The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` for bitwise `OR` with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = np.where((df1>=0.50) | (df1 <=-0.50),df1*df2.shift(-1),0)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df3)
          A        B
0  0.000000  0.00000
1  0.000000  0.01500
2  0.000000  0.00000
3 -0.121200 -0.00755
4  0.010905  0.00000
5  0.000000  0.00000
6  0.000000  0.00065
7  0.000000  0.00000
8 -0.012000 -0.00450
9       NaN      NaN
```

Numpy solution should be faster:

```
arr2 = np.concatenate([df2.values[1:, ], 
                       np.repeat(np.nan, len(df2.columns))[None, :]])

arr = np.where((df1.values>=0.50) | (df1.values <=-0.50),df1.values*arr2,0)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df3)
          A        B
0  0.000000  0.00000
1  0.000000  0.01500
2  0.000000  0.00000
3 -0.121200 -0.00755
4  0.010905  0.00000
5  0.000000  0.00000
6  0.000000  0.00065
7  0.000000  0.00000
8 -0.012000 -0.00450
9       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: It works, thank you for the explanation. Last one: I tried it on the real dataframes and I got the error:  operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3951,1056) (7902,2112). I checked the dimension of the two dataframes before doing the computation and they are both (3951,1056). Not sure why it doubled the size of the second dataframe. Thanks

Comment: Maybe problem different index or columns names, try change `df1*df2.shift(-1)` to `df1.values*df2.shift(-1).values`

Comment: It is working now with this. Also tried your second solution with numpy, working as well. Thank you!

Comment: First solution fails. `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,2) (10,4) ()`

Comment: Yes. This has been discussed in the comments, it works if you add `.values`